# Restrict a program to use only a specific network adapter 2

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have two PCs; the main PC (let's call it "Main") which is connected to the internet by a wireless network in the house. The other PC is a htpc with xbmc installed (we'll call it "HTPC") which is connected to a big flatscreen TV by HDMI. These two PCs are connected by a network cable (using a gigabit switch). The HTPC also have an USB wlan adapter.
Both PCs have win7 ultimate 64bit installed.

I want to achieve the following:
- The software XBMC (preferably "HTPC"s windows in total) must use ONLY the cabled network when doing the 'heavy lifting' such as playing movies or music from "Main" PC.
- The Wireless USB adapter on the "HTPC" is only to be used for internet and so on, NOT heavy file transfers. I am planning to use this network with my galaxy s3 and the app 'xbmc remote' as a remote control (have tried it, and it works).

HOW i'm going to set this up in practice (restricting network connections, IP setup [static or dynamic?], subnet, gateway and so on...I do not know.

In the future, I plan to let the "HTPC" access internet through "MAIN", but only if I can a) find another way to remote control XBMC (e.g: by purchasing an infrared remote controller), and b) be able to reach HTPC from internet (opening ports BOTH in router AND "Main", which will then be the gateway pc).

I know this may seem like a god damn mess! :D
Ideas on how to do this is appreciated! :D

If you have ideas (that works) on how to do this; please explain step-by-step..I'm not a genius.. :)

---

Click here for a picture of my network for the time being:
http://bildr.no/image/bXc0bjIv.jpeg

Comment: it sounds from the description that you already have your desired situation LAN PC <---> LAN HTPC (since i dont read about a cable to a router) and WIFI PC <--->  WIFI HTPC <---> WIFI Router ? AND... I use my galaxy s4 as XBMC remote and the whole stuff is just "cabled". (except for the galaxy s4)

Comment: Ok...I am not sure if I follow; you mean that this situation, that for me seems like a mess, is in fact what I want?
If so...how can I be sure that only the cabled network will be used for the heavy lifting? And how should I set up the ip range and other network details when it comes to giving "HTPC" internet through "Main"?

Comment: How are you sharing files between the 2 PC's? Your on Win7 so are you just using standard windows file shares, mapping the drives, then accessing the shared files (via XMBC) that way? Or are you using a HomeGroup type setup to share files? Also, what's your current IP scheme like now, not the numbers but are you currently using DHCP or a static scheme for all connected interfaces?